# How to set option "compare text" for MSScriptControl.ScriptControl?

Tags: vb.net, com, scripting

```
  Dim scriptControl As Object = CreateObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl")
  scriptControl.Language = "vbscript"
  Dim result As Object = scriptControl.Eval("""aB""=""AB""")
```

**result** will be **False** since binary compare is the default option in vbscript. But I need to use "option compare text" way. I intend to use StrComp to replace the equal operator, but the expression being evaluated could be very complicated. Any good ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "option compare" in VBScript (only in VB), you must use the [StrComp Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ya4w6fwy.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Simon. You pull my back.